# Analogues of $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

The groups $SU_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ are interesting in geometry, and there is a $2$-to-$1$ map from $SU_2(\mathbb{C})$ to $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$. There are finitely many finite groups in $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ (up to isomorphism), and correspondingly, there are finitely many finite groups in $SU_2(\mathbb{C})$, which are generally called as double groups.

What are the higher dimensional analogues of $SU_2(\mathbb{C})$, $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$, with similar map (as $2$-to-$1$ above), and where we can realize interesting families of finite groups as "subgroups" (as above).

Comment: This is not an answer, but you may enjoy perusing the tables on this page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Lie_groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding generalizing the $2$-to-$1$ map, you want [covering space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) theory. The covering space theory of [Lie groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) is well-understood; every connected Lie group $G$ has a universal cover $\tilde{G}$ which is a [simply connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) Lie group, completely determined by its [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) $\mathfrak{g}$, and the covering map $\tilde{G} \to G$ is the quotient by a discrete [central](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)) subgroup of $\tilde{G}$. So to classify such covering maps it suffices to

- classify simply connected Lie groups (equivalently, Lie algebras) and
- compute their centers.

The classification of Lie algebras is hopeless in general, but it can in some sense (see [Levi decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition)) be reduced to the [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra) case, where amazingly there is a complete classification.

**Example.** If $G = \text{SO}(n)$ is the [special orthogonal group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for $n \ge 3$ the corresponding universal cover is the [spin group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $\text{Spin}(n)$ (so $\text{Spin}(3) \cong \text{SU}(2)$; this is an [exceptional isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_isomorphism)). The spin groups are important in geometry and physics.

**Subexample.** If $G = \text{SO}(4)$ then its universal cover is $\text{Spin}(4)$, which has an exceptional isomorphism with $\text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2)$. As in the case $n = 3$ this exceptional isomorphism can be explained using [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

The simplest introduction to Lie theory I know, which will at least acquaint you with the basic examples, is Stillwell's [Naive Lie theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387782141).

Regarding finite subgroups, one keyword here is "McKay correspondence." You may also be interested in learning about the [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) of finite groups.